# Pyathena set default database?

Tags: python, sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

```
from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd

conn = connect(aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
             aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
             s3_staging_dir='s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/',
             region_name='us-west-2')
res = pd.read_sql("select * from db_name.tablename",conn)
```

How can I specify the database name in the connect framework itself or is there any workaround this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `schema_name` as parameter to `connect()`. The default value is `schema_name='default'`

For example:

```
conn = connect(aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
             schema_name='my_schema',
             aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
             s3_staging_dir='s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/',
             region_name='us-west-2')
```

Comment: Thanks I was using a different region of database due to which this did not work earlier. Now it worked